# jQuery function not working after making an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

There is a dropdown in the page - `ddlFilter`, and also a checkbox (with id 239 inside `divData`) at page load. Changing the value of the dropdown, will make an ajax call and then replace the `divData`'s content with the one that is received. The received content is HTML of another checkbox (say id 249).
When any checkbox is clicked, it should fire `showProduct()`

**ISSUE :** Initially after page load, when I click checkbox 239, `showProduct` is fired. But after changing the dropdown and clicking on checkbox 249, the function isn't fired.

There are no errors in console. I think the event handling is not bound to the asynchrounosly added  checkbox. How can i fix this.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlFilter" runat="server/>

<div id="divData">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkBx" id="239"> --line 1

<!--On changing the dropdown value, line 1 will be replaced by this.-->
<!--<input type="checkbox" class="chkBx" id="249">-->
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#ddlFilter").change(function(){
   //code to make ajax call and bind new html inside divData
 })

 $(".chkBx").change(function(){
   showProduct();
 })
})

function showProduct(){
  alert();
}
```

Comment: Try to have id starting with a character.

Comment: but I'm calling it by css clsas

Comment: Still, you cant get an event attached, because event is attached only once in `$(document).ready()`. When you replace an element without refreshing page, event is gone.So you have to use alternate way.

Comment: Then how do call the function if the IDs are dynamic?

Comment: Try to add a fixed string before numeric id like `"ID249"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 $( "body" ).delegate( ".chkBx", "change", function() {
       showProduct();
    });

    $( "body" ).on("change",".chkBx",function(){
       showProduct();
     });
```

Comment: `$( "body" ).on("change",".chkBx",function(){});`..worked for me

Answer (score 3):

When you replace a DOM element via ajax without refreshing, events are not attached automatically.

You might use

```
$(document).on("change",".chkBx",function(){
   showProduct();
 });
```

Comment: If you want to use `$(".chkBx").click();`, add that code in `Sys.Application.add_load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`, because `Sys.Application.add_load()` is executed after each ajax server trip.

Answer (score 1):

We use Ajax for fulfill our requirement without refreshing page.In your example you are changing dropdown's value then click on any value but in that case jquery events cannot be bind with DOM element.So you have to call your function showProduct at the time of changing the dropdowm value.
Please use below :

```
$(document).on("change",".chkBx",function(){
   showProduct();
});
```